# Why realloc doesn't work in this while loop?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am anxious to know why `realloc()` doesn't work in my loop.I made a `grep` function which i tested on a large text file and suddenly the program crashed telling me *"corruption of the heap"* so I decided to break it up and try it on a smaller scale,but the problem persist.Can someone explain what is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void grep(const char *Pattern,FILE *file);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    if(fopen_s(&file,"file.txt","r"))
        return 1;
    grep("word",file);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

void grep(const char *Pattern,FILE *file)
{
    size_t size = 5*sizeof(char);
    char *_Buf = (char*)malloc(size);
    int n = 0, c;
    while(c=getc(file))
    {
        _Buf[n++] = c;
        if(c == '\n' || c == EOF)
        {
            _Buf[n] = '\0';
            if(strstr(_Buf,Pattern))
                printf("%s",_Buf);
            if(c == EOF)
                break;
            n = 0;
        }
        if(n == size)
        {
            size += 5;
            realloc(_Buf,size);
        }
    }
    free(_Buf);
}
```

Comment: you must use `_Buf = realloc(_Buf, size);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY isn't it like returns 0 on success?

Comment: `_Buf[n++] = c;` will place a truncated `EOF` value as the last character in your string.  Assuming `EOF` has the `int` value of `-1` and hex value of `0xFFFFFFFF` (32-bit `int`) that will truncate down to `char` value `0xFF`, which effectively prints the same as a space at the end of your output line.  You won't see it, but if you save your output to a file or look at it with a hex editor or similar you'll be wondering where that came from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `realloc()` on a pointer does not *adjust* the old pointer. It deallocates the old pointer and returns a new pointer containing the new allocation. You need to make use of the returned pointer afterwards.

From the `C11` standard, chapter §7.22.3.5, *The `realloc` function*

> `void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);`
>
> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`. [...]

So, you need to collect the returned pointer, check against NULL and assign it back to the previous pointer, as you may.

That said, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.My mistake was a total blunder.As for not casting the result of `malloc` I know that,i have seen it like million times on SO,however am using c++ compiler,so that's why i cast :)

Comment: @machine_1 You're welcome. Just saying, stick to a C compiler for compiling C code.

Answer (score 4):

You are not assinging the returned pointer of `realloc()` to a variable/pointer:

```
realloc(_Buf,size);
```

Use:

```
char * _New_Buf = realloc(_Buf,size);
if(_New_Buf != NULL)
    _Buf = _NewBuf;
else
    ; // add some error handling here
```

Otherwise, `free()` will also be free-ing the wrong memory pointed to by a possible invalid `_Buf`.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).